# highest and lowest of data attribute jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the highest and lowest values of data attributes of HTML elements.

To explain this better I've created this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d7Lb8vfo/).

and this is my jQuery code:

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(".allPro").each(function() {
        var price = parseInt((this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        if (isNaN(id)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price; }
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price; }
    });
    return [min, max];
}

alert(minMaxId('a'));
```

When I run this code, I should get the max and min values in the alert window but I get nothing for some reason!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check your console? You should be using `$(this)` instead of `(this)`.

Comment: @Terry, yes, sorry that was a typo. but i still get no alert window even with the $ sign.

Answer (score 2):

Here is edit of your code:
Function should not have independent variables.
so I add attrName and fixed selector in your code.

```
function minMaxId(selector,attrName) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).attr(attrName), 10);
        if (isNaN(price)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price; }
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price; }
    });
    return [min, max];
}

alert(minMaxId(".allPro","data-price"));
```

Comment: This works fine too. any suggestion on how to create variables from the above code like  var minimum =  min and  var maximum =  max and then use those variables ?

Answer (score 1):

here is the code you expecting. why you use a parameter

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(".allPro").each(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        if (isNaN(price)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price; }
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price; }
    });
    return [min, max];
}
```

inside the function ther is no use of parameter you passed

Comment: Great. that works, is it possible to create variables like maximum and minimum? Example:  var maximum = ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price; }

Answer (score 0):

First off what you do wrong: you return an array so access that.
Change your alert to `alert(minMaxId('a')[0]);` alerts the min value; `alert(minMaxId('a')[1]);` and the max value.

```
var mythings = minMaxId('a');
alert("Min:" + mythings[0] + " Max:" + mythings[1]);
```

Revised to use basic number not parseint, use the selector, and an object not an array:

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        var price = Number($(this).data("price"));
        if (isNaN(price)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price; }
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price; }
    });
    return {Min:min, Max:max};
}
var prices = minMaxId('a.allPro')
alert("Min:"+prices.Min+" Max:"+prices.Max);
```

OK, this is most likely going to be **way overkill for your purpose** but you can take the good parts out as needed.

I noted in your fiddle that you are using prices NOT integers then parse to integers?  SO we fix that in a parse function - improve and change it to match your needs but basically it handles more/better numbers (not perfect but you can start with it perhaps).  There are likely libraries that do this more extensively you can go to for more examples.

Second, you MIGHT want to have more than one list, or whatever SO, I show you how to create an instance with a min/max for the prices within that list.  Use that part if you need or refactor to use what you want from this.

Here is a fiddle with a click handler etc. so you can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/gcgcqc8d/

Some markup (revised) with some different "prices" to illustrate the parse a bit as well as the "group of prices" concept.

```
<div id="pricelist" class="pricelist">
<a class="allPro" data-price="119.99">19.99</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="115.99">15.99</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="150">$50</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="118">18</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="120.500">20.500</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="116">6</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="111.40">1.40</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="$110.50">$0.50</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="110.02">-0.02</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="empty-)">empty</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="$110.11)">$0.08</a>
</div>
<div id="pricelist2" class="pricelist">
<a class="allPro" data-price="19.99">19.99</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="15.99">15.99</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="50">$50</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="18">18</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="20.500">20.500</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="6">6</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="1.40">1.40</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="$0.50">$0.50</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="0.02">-0.02</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="23e+2">empty</a>
<a class="allPro" data-price="($0.1)">$0.08</a>
</div>
```

Here is the code:

```
"use strict";
function makeClassStrict() {
    var isInternal, instance;
    var constructor = function (args) {
        if (this instanceof constructor) {
            if (typeof this.init == "function") {
                this.init.apply(this, isInternal ? args : arguments);
            }
        } else {
            isInternal = true;
            instance = new constructor(arguments);
            isInternal = false;
            return instance;
        }
    };
    return constructor;
}
var PriceClass = makeClassStrict();
PriceClass.prototype.init = function (siblingselector, groupselector, min, max) {
    var defaultSelector = '.allPro';
    var defaultGroupSelector = '.pricelist';
    this.defaultMin = null;
    this.defaultMax = null;
    this.defaultPrice = null;
    this.selector = siblingselector ? siblingselector : jQuery(defaultSelector).first();
    this.groupSelector = groupselector ? groupselector : jQuery(defaultGroupSelector).first();
    this.min = min ? min : this.defaultMin;
    this.max = max ? max : this.defaultMax;
    this.priceData = "price";
    this.Prices = [];
    this.ReturnjQuerySelector = function (selector) {
        if (selector instanceof jQuery) {
            return selector;
        } else {
            return jQuery(selector);
        }
    };
    this.SetMinMaxPrice(this.selector);
};
PriceClass.prototype.ParsePrice = function (stringPrice) {
    /* will remove all non digits and leave dots and dashes */
    this.regex = (/[^0-9\.\-]+/g);
    var me = this;
    var priceStr = stringPrice + "";
    var number = Number(priceStr);//handle scientific notation like 2e+5
    /* leading parenthesis change to dash */
    /* remove all non digits and leave dots and dashes */
    number = isNaN(number) ? Number(priceStr.replace('(', '-').replace(me.regex, "")) : number;
    return number;
};
/* sets the array of prices */
PriceClass.prototype.SetPrices = function (selector) {
    var me = this;
    var myselector = me.ReturnjQuerySelector(selector);
    myselector.siblings().addBack().each(function () {
        var myprice = me.ParsePrice($(this).data(me.priceData));
        if (isNaN(myprice)) {
            /* return a default price */
            var price = {
                Description: $(this).text(),
                Price: me.defaultPrice
            };
            me.Prices.push(price);
        } else {
            var price = {
                Description: $(this).text(),
                Price: myprice
            };
            me.Prices.push(price);
        }
    });
};
PriceClass.prototype.SetMinMaxPrice = function (selector) {
    var self = this;
    var myselector = self.ReturnjQuerySelector(selector);
    self.SetPrices(myselector);
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < self.Prices.length; i++) {
        var myprice = self.Prices[i].Price;
        if ((self.min === self.defaultMin) || (myprice < self.min)) {
            self.min = myprice;
        }
        if ((self.max === self.defaultMax) || (myprice > self.max)) {
            self.max = myprice;
        }
    }
};
$('.pricelist').on('click', '.allPro', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    /* create and process instance */
    var newprices = PriceClass($(this));
    $('#result').html("MinMax min:" + newprices.min + "<br /> max:" + newprices.max);
});
// change one list to display the price values as text
$('#pricelist').find('.allPro').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).data('price'));
});
console.clear();
/* sets a price using the first group */
$('.allPro').eq(0).trigger('click');
```